# Closing notification tab on swipe

Tags: android

I implemented a very basic demonstration of a service with an asynctask and notifications:

```
public class ImageSendEmailService extends Service implements EmailCallback {
    private static final int IMAGE_SEND_EMAIL_SERVICE_ID = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ForegroundServiceTags.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION.getValue())) {
            EmailTask emailTask = new EmailTask();
            emailTask.setCallback(this);
            emailTask.execute();
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onEmailSendingStarted() {}

    @Override
    public void onEmailSendingProgressUpdate(String progressMessage) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Progress");
        builder.setContentText(progressMessage);
        builder.setTicker("Notification!");
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Notification notification = builder.build();

        this.startForeground(IMAGE_SEND_EMAIL_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmailSendingCompleted() {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Progress");
        builder.setContentText("Progress completed");
        builder.setTicker("Notification!");
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Notification notification = builder.build();

        this.startForeground(IMAGE_SEND_EMAIL_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }
}   

public class EmailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private EmailCallback callback = null;
    private int progress = 0;
    private String progressMessage = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        this.callback.onEmailSendingStarted();

        for (this.progress = 0; this.progress <= 10; this.progress++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            this.progressMessage = String.valueOf((int) (100 * this.progress / 10)) + " %";
            this.publishProgress();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        this.callback.onEmailSendingProgressUpdate(this.progressMessage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        this.callback.onEmailSendingCompleted();
    }

    public void setCallback(EmailCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
}
```

As you can see i did not set my notification to be ongoing but the notification is still not killable. I want the notification to stay as long as the user decides to swipe it away from the notification bar.

How can i do that?

And btw. can i also make a warning or something when the user swipes away a notification which could kill a long running process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the notification to stay as long as the user decides to swipe
>   it away from the notification bar.

`builder.setAutoCancel(false);` will make your notification remain in place even if the user clicks it. The user has to swipe it away.

`builder.setOngoing(true)` will make your notification unswipeable.

Do not use these two together unless you have some other way of removing the notification.

> can i also make a warning or something when the user swipes away a notification which could kill a
>   long running process?

A foreground service should use an ongoing notification (so the user does not kill it unintentionally by swiping) which will launch an activity when clicked. This activity may contain the following:

- Stop button
- Current state of the service
- Results so far
- etc.

Search [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html) for `setContentIntent` to find out how to launch an activity by clicking on notification.